# CSVReader reads text in numeric / general field as empty string while mapping to string type field

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I have text content in a csv field of type numeric/general. In the `CSVClassMap` I have the field mapped to a string. Because of this it reads this CSV field as an empty string. I am reading csv records as below

```
List <CreateEmployer> = CsvReader.GetRecords<CreateEmployer>().ToList();
```

My CSVClassMap code is below

```
public class EmployerMap : CsvClassMap<CreateEmployer> 
{
          public EmployerMap()
            {
               this.Map(m => m.EmployerCredential).Name("Credential");
            }
}
```

My class to which the CSV fields are mapped is below.

```
public class CreateEmployer
{
    public string  EmployerCredential {get; set;}   
}
```

The idea is for the content of CSV field `Credential`(of type General or Numeric) to be read as is by the csv reader and do the validation myself. I cannot change the C# field `EmployerCredential` to be integer instead of string, because of my requirements. How can I make the CSV reader not skip the content of `Credential` field even if its a numeric or general type and map it to my string field `EmployerCredential`? Eg: the field `Credential` in CSV can be of type Numeric and content can be `my sample text`. How do I store this to my .net field `EmployerCredential` ignoring the fact that the text content comes from a numeric type csv field.

After more research I see I need to use Custom TypeConverter, but I cannot find pointers on how I can convert CSV field type `General` or `numeric` to C# type string.

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Please find the edited version to find the relevant code